# How to get only checked elements from a form in shopify?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

```
{% assign type_bonbon = "Sans sucre, Gélifié, Guimauve, Nougat, Acide, Doux" | split : ", " %}
<section class="page__content">
  {% capture contact_form %}
    <div class="contact">
      {% form 'contact', class: 'contact__form' %}
        <div class="form__control">
            <label class = "form__label" for="contact__type_bonbon">Types de bonbons</label>
            {% for type in type_bonbon %}
              <div class = "checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="contact__type_bonbon" name="contact[type]" value="{{type_bonbon}}">{{type}}
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
      {% endform %}
    </div>
  {% endcapture %}
</section>
```

Hello everyone,
I am struggling to Get every checked values within the checkbox.
Right now im getting only the last checked value
I know in PHP we would use the GET method in order to put the "checked" method to every checkbox checked, however, idk how to proceed in shopify.

Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked and I was able to replicate the behavior that you mentioned above about receiving only the last checked value. I don't know if it is a bug or feature from Shopify, but you can use a workaround like below where each field is named differently. Another minor thing is the ID attribute needs to be unique while it generates the same in your for loop above. Besides, that for value it should have been `value="{{type}}"` instead of `value="{{type_bonbon}}"` as **type_bonbon** is an array.

```
{% assign type_bonbon = "Sans sucre, Gélifié, Guimauve, Nougat, Acide, Doux" | split : ", " %}
<section class="page__content">
  {% capture contact_form %}
    <div class="contact">
      {% form 'contact', class: 'contact__form' %}
        <div class="form__control">
            <label class = "form__label" for="contact__type_bonbon">Types de bonbons</label>
            {% for type in type_bonbon %}
              <div class = "checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="contact[type-{{type}}]" value="{{type}}">{{type}}
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
      {% endform %}
    </div>
  {% endcapture %}
</section>
```

Only this line of code is changed, to generate new field name for each type.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="contact[type-{{type}}]" value="{{type}}">{{type}}
```